# Does python have a shorthand for this simple task?

Tags: python

I've just started to learn the long-heard python language. I've been working with C before. And I find python, as a modern script language is much concise on various tasks.

So I was wondering, if I have a list `foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, and I want to pick all the odd numbers out of it into `bar`. In C, I might use a loop and check each number in `foo` and copy the elements needed into `bar`. What do you guys do this "python-style"?

Comment: for that particular example you can use foo[::2] also.

Comment: foo[::2] is called "slice" in Python, look up that word to understand better ChessMaster's example. It works well in this particular case because the odd numbers coincidentally occupy odd positions in the list (even, for zero-based).

Comment: Run through the official tutorial (http://docs.python.org/tutorial/).  It's pretty short and would have answered this question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
bar = [x for x in foo if x % 2 == 1]
```

This form is called ["list comprehension"](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk). In its basic form, it has 4 parts:

1. What you want to include in the output list. Can be any expression involving the variable(s) defined in the second part (below). In this case, the element `x`, unmodified;
2. A variable, or expression, denoting an element of the input list. Following the **for** keyword, each element of the list will be bound to that variable (if your list contains complex objects, you can use [destructuring assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3951946/520779) to refer only to specific parts of it). In this case, each item of the list is bound to `x`;
3. The input list. Following the **in** keyword, the list (or other iterable) where you'll get your elements from. In this case, `foo`;
4. A condition that the element must meet to be included in the result (optional). If included, add the keyword **if** followed by an expression to determine whether or not that element will be included in the output list. In this case, it will be if the number is odd.

Comment: What is this structure called? I need a name so that I can learn this in the documentation.

Comment: @trVoldemort I was updating my answer (wanted to give a quick answer first, then elaborate...), there's more info now.

Comment: @nikow true. Personally, I don't like relying on 0 and non-zero for falsehood/truehood, preferring to be explicit about it. Been bitten many times in the past by errors related to this... (admittedly, not in Python, but in JavaScript, that has much more lousy semantics; but the scars remain)

Comment: @nikow For reference, Google's [Python style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html?showone=True/False_evaluations#True/False_evaluations) suggests using the implicit truth value, but [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) doesn't seem to care.

Answer (score 5):

`filter` function is what you are looking for:

```
bar = filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 1, foo)
```

The expression `lambda x: x % 2 == 1` is basically equivalent to

```
def isOdd(x):
    return x % 2 == 1
```

Comment: What if I want `bar` to be `[1*2, 3*2, 5*2]`? Can I use lambda expression to map it?

Comment: No, you need to use `map` function for that :) You can either combine `filter` and `map` as `map(lambda x: x * 2, filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 1, foo))` or use list comprehension as suggested by mgibsonbr.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a list for what lambda expressions can do? I think list comprehension is short and convenient, but not as universal as lambda.

Comment: `map`, `reduce` and `filter` are three functions you can use for list manipulation. Here is a tutorial that explains all of them: http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_fncs_map_filter_reduce.html

`lambda` notation is not specific to list manipulation operations. It is just a way of defining anonymous functions inside an expression.

Comment: @trVoldemort maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/890128/520779) will help. IMHO the main advantage of `lambda` is allowing you to define very small functions in-place, so you don't have to declare them elsewhere before using them. For instance, to sort your list in descending order, you could use `foo.sort(lambda a,b: b-a)`. Without the lambda, you'd have to write a comparison function first and then pass it to `sort` (maybe never using that function elsewhere).